# DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds vs DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

What is the difference between this two?
Both of them are number of seconds elapsed since you know when.
So there is no difference right?
I want to save this value in MySQL db as a article publish time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're the same. The epoch is defined in [Zulu time, i.e. UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 [...] 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

See also [the docs for `ToUnixTimeSeconds()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds?view=net-5.0):

> This method first converts the current instance to UTC before returning its Unix time.

So it doesn't matter whether you first convert the current time to UTC by calling `UtcNow`, or let the method you want to use do the same.

Comment: Thank You CodeCaster. I read something about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem . If I save this value as a varchar I will be fine. Right?

Comment: @Vahid2015 no, that's a horrible solution. Why not just use a datetime column?

Comment: Can you edit your question and tell me why? Because I'm just saving the number of seconds and nothing else. So I can convert it back anytime I want. Thank You

Comment: "Why not store a number in a varchar column" is a different question.